# Segmentation fault when trying to print linked list C

Tags: c, list, fault

I am trying to print my linked list until the next node is NULL but I am seg faulting after printing two nodes. mov is my linked list nodes.

```
while(mov->next != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", mov->movie_title);
    printf("%s\n", mov->...etc...)

    free(mov);
    mov = mov->next;
}
```

This is my push function that I use to assign the data to the nodes.

```
void push(movie** mov)
{
    movie* new = malloc(sizeof(movie));
    new->next = (*mov);
    (*mov) = new;
}
```

After assigning the data to the node, I call push(&mov);

I was using an array of structs before but since the amount of memory needed to store became very large, I thought it wouldn't work very well since malloc allocates a contiguous block of memory where as with nodes, I can allocate small chunks of memory for each node.

Comment: Question: How do you ensure `mov->next` is NULL for the last node?

Comment: Ouch! `free(mov);` and afterwards `mov = mov->next;`. You may not access data which has been `free`-d.

Comment: You should read this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in the **free(mov)** line and what comes after.

You're freein' mov then trying to assign mov->next to it, you see where the problem is, no ?
**mov->next can't be accessed anymore since you free'd the struct which was storing it**

A better way to print an entire linked list is to set a "temporary" variable which will browse each node of the list and print every values while doing it.

**Here's an example :**

```
void printMovieList(movie** mov) {
    movie* temp = *mov;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp->movie_title);
        printf("%s\n", temp->...etc...);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn I feel dumb, that was so obvious. Thanks.